# NFT-pallet with conflicting implementation

Tags: polkadot, pallet, orml

I've been trying to update the [Litentry NFT pallet](https://github.com/litentry/litentry-pallets) to the latest polkadot branch (v0.9.16). We want to incorporate the pallet in our own project for [Fair Squares](https://github.com/Fair-Squares/fair-squares)

Besides the substrate dependencies, the pallet also relies on 2 [orml](https://github.com/open-web3-stack/open-runtime-module-library) pallets and has an implementation file with `impl_nonfungibles.rs` for the nonfungibles traits that is giving me a hard time to get a successful `cargo check`

The error mentions that there is a `conflicting implementation for 'pallet::Pallet<_>'` The code implementation doesn't look conflicting to me as the implementation in the `lib.rs` and `impl_nonfungibles.rs` look very similar and should work in relation with each other.

The output of one of the two errors is as following:

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `frame_support::traits::tokens::nonfungibles::Inspect<_>` for type `pallet::Pallet<_>`
   --> pallets/nft/src/lib.rs:609:1
    |
609 | impl<T: Config> Inspect<T::AccountId> for Pallet<T> {
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ conflicting implementation for `pallet::Pallet<_>`
    |
   ::: pallets/nft/src/impl_nonfungibles.rs:7:1
    |
7   | impl<T: Config> Inspect<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId> for Pallet<T> {
    | ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- first implementation here
```

These are the code blocks-blocks for lines of the conflicts:

**lib.rs**

```
impl<T: Config> Inspect<T::AccountId> for Pallet<T> {
    type InstanceId = T::TokenId;
    type ClassId = ClassIdOf<T>;
    
    fn owner(class: &Self::ClassId, instance: &Self::InstanceId) -> Option<T::AccountId> {
        orml_nft::Pallet::<T>::tokens(class, instance).map(|t| t.owner)
    }
}
```

**impl_nonfungibles.rs**

```
impl<T: Config> Inspect<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId> for Pallet<T> {
    type InstanceId = T::TokenId;
    type ClassId = T::ClassId;

    fn owner(
        class: &Self::ClassId,
        instance: &Self::InstanceId,
    ) -> Option<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId> {
        orml_nft::Pallet::<T>::tokens(class, instance).map(|a| a.owner)
    }

    fn class_owner(class: &Self::ClassId) -> Option<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId> {
        orml_nft::Pallet::<T>::classes(class).map(|a| a.owner)
    }
//snip
```

The traits that are being use for `frame_support` can be found [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/support/src/traits/tokens/nonfungibles.rs) and the current forked code-base this issue is created for can be found [here](https://github.com/Fair-Squares/litentry-pallets/tree/fs-nft-v0.9.16).

Comment: It looks like the compiler is correctly pointing out that you're trying to implement the same trait on the same thing twice. I think you probably want to delete the code in `lib.rs`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is implementing `Inspect` two times, so the compiler is complaining about conflicting implementation.

I recommend removing the `lib.rs` implementation and keep things only in the `impl_nonfungibles.rs`.

Comment: That works indeed, removed the lib.rs implementation and an additional `#[pallet::without_storage_info]` was required for it to work.